# Unity JS and XML. Getting items

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm working in Unity to create an easy way to create missions for the game I'm making. So I decided to do a test to see if I can make it work properly though an XML file. My XML file is valid. So can someone help me here?

```
import System.Xml;
import System.IO;

function Start () {
    var mission = getXMLFile("C:/test.plz");
    //Debug.Log(mission);
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(mission);
    xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("mission");
    Debug.Log(xmlDoc['stages'].id['1']['hud_icon']);
}
```

The other function to get the XML file is this:

```
function getXMLFile(filepathIncludingFileName : String) {
    var sr = new File.ReadAllText(filepathIncludingFileName);
    return sr;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, you do: `xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("mission");`.

This should be: `XmlNodeList missionList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("mission");`

With this, you can do anything with those missions.

```
foreach (XmlNode missionInfo in missionList)
{
    XmlNodeList missioncontent = missionInfo.ChildNodes;

    foreach (XmlNode missionItems in missioncontent) //The nodes
    {
        if(missionItems.Name == "stages")
        {
             //You'll have the stage
        }
        if(levelsItens.Name == "hud_icon")
        {
             //You'll have the hud icon object
        }
        if(levelsItens.Name == "id")
        {
             //You'll have the ID
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, got me in the right direction for parsing mission XML files.